# Can someone answer why this Tkinter doesn't work?

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter, passwords, python-3.6

## I'M SO CONFUSED

**Keep in mind that I'm a beginner at programming/python so if my code is unorganized or badly worded, ignore it, I'm getting better lol**

I'm just playing with tkinter and I'm trying to get a login screen that has a checkbox that toggles the visibility of the password. I just don't understand anymore. The "show" argument won't change based on the variable it was assigned and I don't know why.

```
showPassword = IntVar()
show = None

def apply():
    print(showPassword.get())
    sspass = showPassword.get()
    print(type(sspass))
    if sspass == 1:
        show = None
    elif sspass == 0:
        show = "*"


spB = Checkbutton(root, text="Toggle Show Password", variable=showPassword).grid(row=10, column=1)

applyButton = Button(root, text="Apply", command=apply).grid(column=1, row=5)

Password = entry(root, show=show)
```

Comment: No one will be able tell you why your code doesn't work if you don't describe what it's meant to be doing.

Comment: @eugenhu I did :"I'm trying to get a login screen that has a checkbox that toggles the visibility of the password"

Comment: Yes but what's wrong with the code that you've included in your question, there is no password input widget or anything, what is it supposed to be doing?

Comment: @eugenhu sorry lol, I fixed it. It was late at night when I posted this, and I couldn't think properly lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have arranged a snippet of code (that is not perfect for you to follow but...) based on yours that at least works for you to progress. Your code is incomplete I suppose, it has also some errors. You have to configure the show parameter in the widget. Changing your show var won't do anything to the widget.
You'll have to use the form `widget['show'] = somevalue`. Or the `.configure`widget method. For both you'll need a widget reference. If you grid a widget in the same line you create it, `grid` will return nothing so you loose it. Break that in two steps and keep the reference for the widget at creation (first step). `entry` is actually called `Entry`. These where the most prominet errors I saw.

```
from tkinter import Button, Checkbutton, Entry, Tk, IntVar

root = Tk()

showPassword = IntVar()
show = None

def apply():
    print(showPassword.get())
    sspass = showPassword.get()
    print(type(sspass))
    if sspass == 1:
        Password['show'] = "" 
    elif sspass == 0:
        Password['show'] = "*"
    Password.update()


spB = Checkbutton(root, text="Show Password", variable=showPassword).grid(row=10, column=1)

applyButton = Button(root, text="Apply", command=apply).grid(column=1, row=5)

Password = Entry(root, show=show)
Password.grid(row=3, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I did state in my question that I am a beginner and I am sick of the criticism lmfaoo

Comment: @StevenTautonico don't get me wrong. I meant my snippet is not a perfect example for you to follow. I was not referring to your code, but mine. I understood you are a beginner, just tried to help. Don't mind the criticism, just search your problem first in docs and SO answers, and when posting the question show some effort by posting an mcve with your failing code (which you did). You'll usually get help pretty fast. You can improve the post by edit but If downvotes go too far you can delete the post, improve it and post it later.

Comment: thank you though, I really appriciate the help, I just get really annoyed because, even though I state that I'm a beginner, most people instantly assume that I'm not and shit talk me and criticize me. I misread your words, but thanks, I appriciate

Comment: oh, and I googled the hell out of it, couldn't find anything lol

Comment: @StevenTautonico search in SO with [tkinter] tag. There is plenty of info here. Google would probably send you over here anyway. Find a good tutorial on tkinter. Try here http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html. tkinter can be confusing at first. Search for python tutorials too. Learning tkinter without knowing python basics well will be much more intriguing.

Comment: I've seen a lot of the tutorials, but i just couldn't find one that had what I needed, or I didn't make sense of it.

Comment: @StevenTautonico tkinter is both simple, powerful and full of complex details, depending on what you are trying to do. What you felt is also part of it :)